# Evo pdf does not work with localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, evopdf

I m using evo pdf to convert html to pdf file,

```
 PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();
 //license, credantials
 pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderHeight = 70;
 pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.DrawHeaderLine = false;

 pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.TextArea = new TextArea(495, 10, "Sayfa &p; / &P;", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8));
 pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterHeight = 20;
 pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.DrawFooterLine = false;
 pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.RightMargin = 20;
 pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.LeftMargin = 20;
 pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.TopMargin = 20;
 pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.BottomMargin = 20;
 pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.FitWidth = true;

 pdfConverter.SavePdfFromUrlToFile(pdfUrl,path);
```

and my pdf path starts with localhost

but it is not working with localhost. Is there any way to test evo pdf in my local

Answer (score 0):

Does pdfUrl point to a HTML page or a PDF document? It is expected to point to a HTML page which can be a localhost URL without problems as long as the HTML page is loaded well in a browser. 
The path parameter is expected to be the path to output file on local computer.